# Pick words from list that start with a character from a list of valid characters

Tags: python, list, for-loop

For the character `F` only:

```
sportslist = ["Football" , "Fencing" , "Cricket" , "Basketball" , "Baseball" , "Tennis"]
newl = []

for word in sportslist:
    if word.startswith('F'):
        newl.append(word)
        print (newl)
```

Output:

```
['Football'] , ['Fencing']
```

I used the `for` loop to obviously repeat the coding but for some reason when I try print out multiple words beginning with another letter, say I wanted to print out the words beginning with `F` and `B`. How would I execute that as I just get a blank output?

Comment: Words cannot start with F and B... Surely you mean F **or** B? That being said, what issues are you having?

Comment: "*but for some reason when I try print out multiple words beginning with another letter*" Please show your attempt to do this, as it's not clear what exact issue you are having and why you are getting a blank output.

Comment: like i get no output nothing just a blank screen on my python software

Comment: The code you posted does not produce a "blank output". That is why we are asking to post how you tried to "*print out multiple words beginning with another letter*", so hopefully someone can point out your mistake.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq `str.startswith()` can take a tuple of strings to match, and doesn't break if one of the items is an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

- a *tuple of all accepted starting strings* (as an argument of the `.startswith()` method),
- (eventually) a *list comprehension*
  (instead of your `for` loop with the `if` statement and the `.append()` method):

```
sportslist = ["Football" , "Fencing" , "Cricket" , "Basketball" , "Baseball" , "Tennis"]

newl = [word    for word in sportslist    if word.startswith(("F", "B"))]
print(newl)
```

---

> ```
> ['Football', 'Fencing', 'Basketball', 'Baseball']
> ```

---

*Note:*

I added *superfluous spaces* into the list comprehension to emphasize its 3 parts:

1. `word` - what to add into the target list,
2. `for word in sportslist` — from where is `word` in the point 1. iteratively obtained,
3. `if word.startswith(("F", "B"))` - which condition must `word` from the point 2. satisfy.

Comment: One could also format comprehensions with newlines instead of spaces. (It also looks more understandable to beginners.)

Answer (score 1):

You could do an `or` and apply another `startswith` for `B`, that would work:

```
for word in eustates:
    if word.startswith('F') or word.startswith('B'):
        newl.append(word)
        print (newl)
```

Or you could try:

```
for word in eustates:
    if word[:1] in 'BF':
        newl.append(word)
        print (newl)
```

Or:

```
for word in eustates:
    if 'BF'.__contains__(word[:1]):
        newl.append(word)
        print (newl)
```

Comment: Nit picking: Note that the second and third methods will fail with empty strings. Also using dunder methods is discouraged.

Comment: @Selcuk Edited it.

Comment: I don't think that would fix it. `"" in "BF"` will return `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a *tuple* `('F', 'B')` as an argument of the `.startswith()` method and *correct the indentation of the last line of your code:*

```
sportslist = ["Football" , "Fencing" , "Cricket" , "Basketball" , "Baseball" , "Tennis"]
newl = []

for word in sportslist:
    if word.startswith(('F', 'B')):
        newl.append(word)
print (newl)                         # <------------ no indentation!
```

Comment: It makes more sense to add this as an alternative method to your previous answer instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get fancy and complicate things, then you can use the `filter` function:

```
sportslist = ["Football" , "Fencing" , "Cricket" , "Basketball" , "Baseball" , "Tennis"]
letters = ('F', 'B')
new1 = list(filter(lambda item:item.startswith(letters), sportslist))
print(new1)
#['Football', 'Fencing', 'Basketball', 'Baseball']    # <-- output
```